# Unable to do a JOIN when having the same table with two different names

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
SELECT count(a.id) from hist a, hist b
JOIN acq c on acq.id = a.id
where a.status = 'OK'
and b.status = 'passed'
and a.id = b.id
and c.src = 'g9x'
and a.timestamp - b.timestamp > 30
```

I am counting all values with those parameters, but I believe the issue is because I am naming the table hist two times, this is because I am subtracting two parameters in that table to see if its greater than 30 this is the only way to do it as this is the only table with these values, I am trying to join a different table to get the last value.

how can this be performed with naming the table twice ?

I am getting this error.

"A.id invalid identifier ORA-00904

Comment: Are you sure your table has a column `id`? What happens if you do something like this: `select id from hist where rownum = 1`? If you get an error, let us know. There are various things that may cause that, but first figure out exactly what the problem is; this would be an important first step.

Comment: This is a faq, comma has lower precedence than keyword joins.

Comment: @philipxy - How is that related to the OP's question?

Comment: @mathguy It gives the reason for the error & points out that reasonable research obviates the post.

Comment: @philipxy - The error is "invalid identifier". How is that specific error related to what you said? If you actually think they are related, please say why you believe that (link to documentation, or a small example, etc.)

Comment: @mathguy I suggest you follow up with what I already wrote. PS I commented because the post should be closed but I still gave them the answer. PS I'm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining using old comma style join syntax, use standard syntax like `INNER JOIN` between your two `hist` tables. So your query would look like this:

```
SELECT count(a.id) 
from hist a
INNER JOIN hist b
  ON a.id = b.id
JOIN acq c 
  on c.id = a.id
where a.status = 'OK'
  and b.status = 'passed'
  and c.src = 'g9x'
  and a.timestamp - b.timestamp > 30
```

Comment: oh sorry woops it works for that colum now, the issue is line 5 being
C.id = A.id and it saying invalid identifier aswell

Comment: @user5428151 are you certain of the column existence? This demo shows that the syntax should work - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76300/2/0